# If $X$ is a Gaussian random variable, what is the distribution of $|X|$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

> Say $X$ is a normally distributed random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$. What is the distribution of the absolute value of $X$? For some more generality, how about $a|X|$ where $a$ is a positive constant?

Intuitively I would think that it is a Gaussian distribution truncated about the y-axis.

Comment: You will have to scale the density to makes its integral $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x>0$, then
\begin{align}P(|X|\leq x) &= P(-x \leq X \leq x)
\\&=1-2P(X <-x) \\
&=1-2\Phi(-x)\end{align}

Differentiate it to get the pdf.

$$f_{|X|}(x)=2\phi(-x)=2\phi(x)$$

I will leave the case of $a|X|$ as an exercise.